# How to pass a struct from C++ application to a C++ Win32 DLL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, struct

How to pass a struct from C++ application to a C++ Win32 DLL?

Would you please give me an example?

Comment: Do you already know how to make a header file for your DLL, and call a function in your DLL from a C++ program?

Comment: Yes, but i'm not sure is there any problem to pass a struct pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a pointer because the DLL in windows are in the same address space as the program.

Note however that the DLL interface stops there and you (normally) do not have a shared memory management and you cannot in general pass for example an `std::vector` and expect the DLL to be able to `push_back` new elements. The reason is that the DLL has in general its own memory manager and heap, separated from the one of the caller (after all DLL can be called from any language, not necessarily C++).

Even if it may be surprising passing an `std::map` and having the DLL and only just reading it still may not work, because some containers in the standard library depends on "sentinels" and and these could be duplicated for the DLL too.

In the above I used the term "in general" because the DLL may have some trickery to be able to share the memory management with the main process. For example microsoft MFC was designed to work properly around these DLL barriers since VC6 (but NOT the standard library!).

You must also be sure that DLL and the main program are compiled with the exact same compiler and compiling options because otherwise even plain structures may have a different memory layout.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! If my dll will be distributed everywhere, should I just also distribute a .h including the struct then any kinds of languages applications can past dll the struct pointer without any problems?

Comment: Yes... you should state the exact memory layout that the DLL is expecting. Even better would be providing in addition to that examples of code calling your library in different languages.

Answer (score 1):

How is your `struct` defined? Is it a POD? Is it a simple C `struct`? Or is it a `struct` that has members that are instances of STL classes?

If the `struct` is a "pure C" `struct`, then you can simply pass it to the DLL.

But if the `struct` has STL classes as data members, then you must be sure that both the .EXE and the .DLL use **dynamic linking to CRT**, and are built with the **same version of Visual C++ compiler** and **same flavor of the CRT** (e.g. you can't pass STL classes at the boundary if you have a debug-build .EXE and a release-build .DLL, because the implementations of the STL containers change from debug to release builds; and you can't pass STL classes at the boundary if you have an .EXE built e.g. with VC10 and a .DLL built with VC9).

Moreover, you may want to read this interesting article on CodeProject: 
**"[HowTo: Export C++ classes from a DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL)"**.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! My struct is pure C, and this is a good example for me to learn more.